# Handling EditText Dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to get Values from EditText dynamically.. I  have a lot of EditText generated when user press add button..When User presses add Button it generates 3 Edittext each time. I dont know how to get the values from this dynamically generated EdiTtext . Now My question is how can i get the values from The 3 Edittext on each row. ALso I need to verify that if user removed the view or not. Please help I am new android development.This should happen when a user presses on Save Button. Thanks in advance!

This is class .

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    Button saveBtn,cancelBtn,addBtn;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    EditText third,first,second;
    LinearLayout Container;
    int counter=0;
    int all=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        saveBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        cancelBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        Container=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        addBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "The Result: "+all,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                        (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
//              EditText ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
//              EditText ed2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//              EditText ed3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
//              all=all+Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString())+Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);                
                    }});
                Container.addView(addView);
            }});
    }

}
```

This is my row.xml .which i am using as a view in java code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Field 1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:inputType="numberPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Remove" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Field 2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
        android:editable="false"
        tools:ignore="Deprecated" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Field 3" />

</RelativeLayout>


This is my layout which is attached with my activity class.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Add" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="146dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="146dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/save"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="T 1"
            tools:ignore="Deprecated" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="T 2"
            tools:ignore="Deprecated" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="T 3"
            tools:ignore="Deprecated" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="T 4"
            tools:ignore="Deprecated,HardcodedText" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u can add tag while creating a edittext dynamically

Comment: well the solution in my opinion is to use a custom listview anything else would make your life miserable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your edited SecondActivity.java

```
   public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    Button             saveBtn, cancelBtn, addBtn;
    RelativeLayout     layout;
    EditText           third, first, second;
    LinearLayout       Container;
    int                counter = 0;
    int                all     = 0;
    int                tag     = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> dynamicLayoutsTags;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        Container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (dynamicLayoutsTags.size() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicLayoutsTags.size(); i++) {
                        View getView = Container
                                .findViewWithTag(dynamicLayoutsTags.get(i));
                        EditText editText1 = (EditText) getView
                                .findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        EditText editText2 = (EditText) getView
                                .findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                        EditText editText3 = (EditText) getView
                                .findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                        Toast.makeText(
                                SecondActivity.this,
                                "Row " + i + " : " + "editext 1 is : "
                                        + editText1.getText()
                                        + " editext 2 is : "
                                        + editText2.getText()
                                        + " editext 3 is : "
                                        + editText3.getText(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "The Result: " + all,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            }
        });

        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                Button buttonRemove = (Button) addView
                        .findViewById(R.id.remove);
                addView.setTag(tag);
                buttonRemove.setTag(tag);
                dynamicLayoutsTags.add(tag);
                Container.addView(addView);
                tag++;
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // ((LinearLayout) addView.getParent())
                        // .removeView(addView);
                        Integer removeTag = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        View deleteView = Container.findViewWithTag(removeTag);
                        Container.removeView(deleteView);
                        dynamicLayoutsTags.remove(removeTag);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tag = 0;
        dynamicLayoutsTags = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you did not get my point..i need to add three EditText when user presses add button..now i want to get the valuea from these 3 edittext from each row.

Comment: yes i point is from above code is , u want you to add tag to that 3 editext and when u add that 3 edittext in layout...u can refer that tag to get values also... i hope i m getting right now....

Comment: I did not try yet.i will let you know.

Comment: :( ok .. i hope i got the question ur expained or m wrong?

Comment: Can you please tell me where to place the code in to my code?

Comment: ohh, ok i have few doubts actually...in code u hv instantiated first,second and third edittext but where hv u putted that in layout ...i mean that is dynamically created na

Comment: Please ignore that i have commented out those lines..please tell me what code do i need to add to get the values from the dynamically created edittext..

Comment: Link..i did not get you..i was wondering if you give a working code on my requirement..i would be grateful to you..

Comment: I have downloaded the app..sign up complete.now what to do?

Comment: noooo y downlaoded i just said to login there so that i can understand ur issue

Comment: O sorry..i dont see the link now.can you come to skype please.if you have no problem..

Comment: i dont hv skype my friend, so asked to come online...no issue...see if u could solved from above my code..any help always welcome

Comment: Ok.then send the link again please. I will log in there..also i have apk.. I would be better if you can test it.i am sure after gerring the apk you will understand my requirement..can u give me ur email so that i can send you the apk.